# Encompassing Trait Objects within a Base Trait Object

Tags: rust

Sorry if this seems trivial, but I'm trying to do a simple operation but am having a tough time doing so. I just want to have two trait objects whereby one has a Vector that contains a bunch of the other object.

```
trait MetaClass {
    fn new() -> Self;
    fn add(&self, subtrait: Box<SubClass>);
}

struct MetaStruct {
    elems: Vec<Box<SubClass>>,
}

impl MetaClass for MetaStruct{
    fn new() -> MetaStruct {
        MetaStruct{
            elems: Vec::new(),
        }
    }

    fn add(&self, subtrait: Box<SubClass>){
        // if I reformulate the above to 'fn add(&self, subtrait: SubClass){'
        // and use the below I get the trait `core::marker::Sized` is not implemented for the type `SubClass`
        //self.elems.push(Box::new(subtrait));
        self.elems.push(subtrait);
    }
}


trait SubClass{
    fn new() -> Self;
}

struct MySubClass {
    data: i32,
}

impl SubClass for MySubClass {
    fn new() -> MySubClass{
        MySubClass{
            data: 10,
        }
    }
}


fn main(){
    let mut meta = Box::new(MetaStruct::new());
    // ideally I just want to do meta.add(MySubClass::new()) but as mentioned above that has some sizing issues :'(
    meta.add(Box::new(MySubClass::new()));
}
```

The error I am getting is:

```
<anon>:45:11: 45:38 error: cannot convert to a trait object because trait `SubClass` is not object-safe [E0038]
<anon>:45   meta.add(Box::new(MySubClass::new()));
                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is a link to rust play: http://is.gd/pjLheJ

I have also tried the following, but got the same error:

```
meta.add(Box::new(MySubClass::new()) as Box<SubClass>);
```

Ideally if there is a way to do this with Rust's static dispatch that would be ideal, but I would be okay with dynamic dispatching as well. In each case I think it will make sense to have the MetaClass actually own the object of the subclass, so I don't want to pass a reference to it, but the entire object itself.

Comment: This was [cross posted to Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/rust/comments/3ebxuy/trouble_understanding_cascading_trait_objects/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to have two trait objects whereby one has a Vector that contains a bunch of the other object.

That's straight-forward enough:

```
trait TraitOne {
    fn add(&mut self, another: Box<TraitTwo>);
}

trait TraitTwo {
    fn value(&self) -> u8; 
}

struct Container(Vec<Box<TraitTwo>>);
impl TraitOne for Container {
    fn add(&mut self, another: Box<TraitTwo>) {
        self.0.push(another);
    }
}

struct ThingOne(u8);
impl TraitTwo for ThingOne {
    fn value(&self) -> u8 { self.0 }
}

struct ThingTwo(u8, u8);
impl TraitTwo for ThingTwo {
    fn value(&self) -> u8 { self.0 + self.1 }
}

fn main() {
    let mut trait_1: Box<TraitOne> = Box::new(Container(vec![]));

    let thing_1: Box<TraitTwo> = Box::new(ThingOne(42));
    let thing_2: Box<TraitTwo> = Box::new(ThingTwo(21, 21));

    trait_1.add(thing_1);
    trait_1.add(thing_2);
}
```

Your real error is about *object safety*. Huon Wilson (a Rust core team member) wrote a [great blog post about this](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/).

In your case you have this trait:

```
trait SubClass{
    fn new() -> Self;
}
```

This is not object safe, quoting Huon (emphasis mine):

> There’s two fundamental ways in which this can happen, as an argument or as a return value, in either case a reference to the Self type means that it must match the type of the self value, the **true type of which is unknown at compile time**.

That is, how many bytes need to be allocated on the stack or heap to hold the object returned by `fn new() -> Self`? You cannot know, because you only have a trait object.

One solution is to make sure that `Self` is `Sized` in your trait, as per the [followup blog post](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/05/where-self-meets-sized-revisiting-object-safety/):

```
trait SubClass {
    fn new() -> Self where Self: Sized;
}
```

Then, just fix some mutability mismatches in your trait, and it compiles.

Comment: Gah, didn't realize it was that easy to implement sized. That simple thing fixed my problem! Thank you again!